# Maven: "Error reading archetype catalog", NOT behind a Proxy

Tags: java, macos, maven, proxy

Command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false -DgroupId=org.apache.solr -DartifactId=es-my-proj
```

Error (full stack at bottom):

```
...
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[WARNING] Error reading archetype catalog http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Access denied to: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 , ReasonPhrase:Denied Access.
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:928)
    ...
```

Every google search I've done comes up with one of these answers, but none of which are applicable:

- Behind a proxy - but I'm not behind a proxy!
- Some bug back in 2010 with Maven 2.x, but I'm on Maven 3.0.5
- Mangled settings file, but I don't even have a ~/.m2/settings.xml file

Other things I've checked:

- Each time I make sure there's no directory and no pom file, etc.
- Also tried adding  -DarchetypeRepository=http://repo2.maven.org/maven2 but same result
- The "Access denied" was odd - I am able to visit both repo1 and repo2 from a browser (though the server says browsing has been disabled of course)
- Maven 3.0.5, Oracle Java 7 (1.7.0_25), on Mountain Lion (OS X 10.8.4)

It does create a project using some 1x template, I don't know how good or bad that is.

Full stack trace:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false -DgroupId=org.apache.solr -DartifactId=my-proj-name
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[WARNING] Error reading archetype catalog http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Access denied to: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 , ReasonPhrase:Denied Access.
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:928)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.source.RemoteCatalogArchetypeDataSource.downloadCatalog(RemoteCatalogArchetypeDataSource.java:119)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.source.RemoteCatalogArchetypeDataSource.getArchetypeCatalog(RemoteCatalogArchetypeDataSource.java:87)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.DefaultArchetypeManager.getRemoteCatalog(DefaultArchetypeManager.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.DefaultArchetypeManager.getRemoteCatalog(DefaultArchetypeManager.java:205)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.ui.generation.DefaultArchetypeSelector.getArchetypesByCatalog(DefaultArchetypeSelector.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.ui.generation.DefaultArchetypeSelector.selectArchetype(DefaultArchetypeSelector.java:71)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.execute(CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.java:197)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[WARNING] No archetype found in remote catalog. Defaulting to internal catalog
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Using following parameters for creating project from Old (1.x) Archetype: maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: org.apache.solr
[INFO] Parameter: packageName, Value: org.apache.solr
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: org.apache.solr
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: my-proj-name
[INFO] Parameter: basedir, Value: /Users/mbennett/dev
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] project created from Old (1.x) Archetype in dir: /Users/mbennett/dev/my-proj-name
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.563s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Aug 27 11:47:28 PDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/206M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I have the same problem with Windows, maven 3.1 and 3.0.5 and Java 1.7.0_9. Tested with your command and also from InteliJ with one of the archetype suggested by the IDE.

Comment: same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495426/maven-access-denied-to-http-repo1-maven-org-maven2. seem to work with maven 2

Comment: @dermoritz THANK YOU for the link, Google kept returning bogus matches.  I'm somewhat comforted to see (in the comments on the other post) how many other people are hitting this, I thought I was goin' nuts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like Apache central repository has fixed the issue. So without making any change, the problem is fixed now. Please try once again and let us know in case of any issue.

Answer (score 3):

The Apache Maven team faced the same issue with one of their integration-tests, see the related [message-thread](http://markmail.org/message/ur3xcvopgxqp7ney).
So it seems that during the last week of August the policy has changed and it is not possible to get these xml files without a User-Agent in the request.
There's no option in the Maven Settings to set this value, neither have I found another way to set it.

I can confirm that Maven-3.0.4 does work, but this version has a [security issue](http://maven.apache.org/security.html). According to other posts other older versions of Maven seem to work as well.

Unless Maven Central changes its policy, this is something which needs to be fixed in the next Maven release.

Comment: User-agent fix will be part of version 3.1.1, see https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5509

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I tried to fix this by my own but it wasn't so easy... I didn't find the source code of wagon-http-2.4-shaded.jar. So i will just wait for the next maven release. By the way, how is it helpful to add a user-agent in the resquest for a ssl security problem ?

Comment: The shaded jar is created together with the wagon-http.jar at https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/maven-wagon.git/?p=maven-wagon.git;a=tree;f=wagon-providers/wagon-http;h=25f01a043ad8bdcbbfced7a9745f2e04ffee0eda;hb=HEAD

Comment: It is not an SSL issue, we're talking about http, not https. The Apache Maven team doesn't maintain Maven Central, so we were suprised as well. For some reason the decision has been made to require the User-Agent for all requests (probably to avoid scrapers). No User-Agent == Access Denied. That's why checking the file with any browser would work.

Comment: Great background info!  For another workaround see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18518117/295802

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error yesterday. I didn't finish to find the solution yet but I have a idea why we have this errror.

After hours of digging in the maven-archetype-plugin, I didn't notice something strange...

So i decide to run the same command again with a tcpflow running to capture the sended request. Here is the result :

```
192.168.000.010.59775-185.031.016.185.00080: GET /maven2/archetype-catalog.xml HTTP/1.1
Cache-control: no-cache
Cache-store: no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Host: repo1.maven.org
Connection: Keep-Alive


185.031.016.185.00080-192.168.000.010.59775: HTTP/1.1 403 Denied Access
Server: Varnish
Retry-After: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 401
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Fri, 30 Aug 2013 01:53:29 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Age: 0
Connection: close
X-Served-By: cache-am70-AMS
X-Cache: MISS
X-Cache-Hits: 0
```

So, a Guru Meditation error. I like Varnish !! After that, I notice using netcat that, if you add a User-Agent (anything) in the request, everything works fine !!

```
[07:49][patouche@patouche-desktop:~ :) ] $ nc repo1.maven.org 80
GET /maven2/archetype-catalog.xml HTTP/1.1
Cache-control: no-cache
Cache-store: no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Host: repo1.maven.org
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: I have a dream...

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.1
Content-Type: text/xml
Last-Modified: Tue, 27 Aug 2013 11:06:25 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Content-Length: 1663366
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Fri, 30 Aug 2013 05:50:09 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Age: 81998
Connection: keep-alive
X-Served-By: cache-c32-CHI, cache-l22-LON
X-Cache: HIT, HIT
X-Cache-Hits: 5, 1
```

So, if you add a User-Agent in the request, everything will work. I thinks with the settings.xml but I don't know how for now.

Comment: A really interesting theory.  See also the comment above from dermoritz