# Maven, Access denied to: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2

Tags: java, maven, build, compilation

I have just downloaded last version of Maven.

And when i am trying to run

> mvn archetype:generate

i get error message

> [WARNING] Error reading archetype catalog
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Access
>   denied to: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 , ReasonPhrase:Denied Access.
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:928)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
>   at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
>   at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61) at
>   org.apache.maven.archetype.source.RemoteCatalogArchetypeDataSource.downloadCatalog(RemoteCatalogArchetypeDataSource.java:119)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.archetype.source.RemoteCatalogArchetypeDataSource.getArchetypeCatalog(RemoteCatalogArchetypeDataSource.java:87)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.archetype.DefaultArchetypeManager.getRemoteCatalog(DefaultArchetypeManager.java:216)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.archetype.DefaultArchetypeManager.getRemoteCatalog(DefaultArchetypeManager.java:205)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.archetype.ui.generation.DefaultArchetypeSelector.getArchetypesByCatalog(DefaultArchetypeSelector.java:200)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.archetype.ui.generation.DefaultArchetypeSelector.selectArchetype(DefaultArchetypeSelector.java:71)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.execute(CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.java:197)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
>   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320) at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156) at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537) at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196) at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
>   [WARNING] No archetype found in remote catalog. Defaulting to internal
>   catalog [INFO] No archetype defined. Using maven-archetype-quickstart
>   (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0)

I have not Proxy and internet works fine. Firewall is turned off. How to solve this problem ?

Thx for your help.

If we look to the class [org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.maven.wagon/wagon-http-shared4/2.1/org/apache/maven/wagon/shared/http/AbstractHttpClientWagon.java)
method fillInputData( InputData inputData ) we can see this:

```
public void fillInputData( InputData inputData )
       throws TransferFailedException, ResourceDoesNotExistException,AuthorizationException
    {
     ....
 HttpResponse response;
     ....
 statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
     ....
 switch ( statusCode )
        {
            case HttpStatus.SC_OK:
                break;

            case HttpStatus.SC_NOT_MODIFIED:
                // return, leaving last modified set to original value so getIfNewer should return unmodified
                return;

            case SC_NULL:
            {
                TransferFailedException e =
                    new TransferFailedException( "Failed to transfer file: " + url + reasonPhrase );
                fireTransferError( resource, e, TransferEvent.REQUEST_GET );
                throw e;
            }

            case HttpStatus.SC_FORBIDDEN:    // <---------THIS
                fireSessionConnectionRefused();
                throw new AuthorizationException( "Access denied to: " + url + reasonPhrase);
       ....
         }
...
}
```

[So problem caused because we have HTTP 403 Forbidden error in response.](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/403error.htm)
But i dont know what to do...

---

So now we know that we are getting FORBIDDEN error because we have not User-Agent in HTTP request. [Thanx to Patouche](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473398/maven-error-reading-archetype-catalog-not-behind-a-proxy/18526471#18526471)

Comment: Did you do any research?  This seems to be a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/q/18473398/18157

Comment: I have tried to do same operations on Windows 7 and linux Kubuntu 13.04, on my laptop and home PC, on different JRE's but nothing :((.

Comment: SO i think it is a connection problem. May be it caused because my provider uses NAT :((

Comment: I am having the same issue. Using mvn 3.0.4 on win7, no proxy, jdk 1.7.0_21 (I know...)

Comment: You're welcome ;-). It's seems that the apache team have already fix this bug. It will be in the next release of maven.

Comment: Good news, Patouche :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems as though directory browsing on http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 has been switched off. I had to resort to getting the archetype catalog myself. I did this:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=archetype-catalog.xml
```

Alternatively I guess you could just download the archetype-catalog.xml file from that link and place it in your .m2 directory as mentioned in this comment:

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ARCHETYPE-202?focusedCommentId=182771&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-182771

Comment: Is there any hope that they will fix this ?

Comment: I hope they will fix this; I currently have no idea and my message to the #maven irc channel has so far gone unanswered. I guess the best bet is to subscribe to the mailing list and ask them there.

Comment: they have to add just one line to  org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon class, to set up user-agent :(

Comment: but this explans not the fact that it is still working with maven 2

Comment: Also hit this over on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473398 and somebody linked to here in the comments. Yes, I hope they fix it - it's madness!  It's particularly annoying because it'll likely be hit by new maven users trying to create their first project, and they'll assume it's some issue with their system.

Comment: It's a nice solution. I prefer to make a wget of the archetype catalog in my .m2 directory until the latest maven release will be out.

Comment: but when will came out 3.1.1 version ?

Comment: Sadly maven 3.1x broke some other stuff I was working with, that's why I had to retreat to 3.0.5.  From this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18550459/295802 I wonder if 3.0.4 might also work.

Comment: for me it was the antivirus/firewall

Answer (score 5):

It seems like Apache central repository has fixed the issue. So without making any change, the problem is fixed now. Please try once again and let us know in case of any issue.

Answer (score 3):

Execute this Command. It will not only create your maven project but also resolve the issue of downloading archetype jar. It is mainly due to unavailability to the archetype URL.

Fill Project Group Id with your project names.

mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId={Project Group Id} -DartifactId={Project Id} -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false -DarchetypeCatalog=http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=archetype-catalog.xml

Answer (score 1):

it seem to work with maven 2 (reproduced the problem on 3 machines linux and windows with maven 3.05 and maven 3.1)

the problem occurs only for the repo1... urls. If you delete your local repository, all plugin downloads will work fine until the download of archetype catalog - "access denied"

Comment: Yes. For me is quite so.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this:

```
>mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=... -DartifactId=... -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.4 -DinteractiveMode=false 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
.  .  .
[WARNING] Error reading archetype catalog http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Failed to transfer file: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required.
.  .  .
[WARNING] No archetype found in remote catalog. Defaulting to internal catalog
.  .  .
```

The project generated successfully but the message didn't look good.

I solved this problem by adding `archetypeCatalog` property into my `settings.xml`:

```
<settings>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>defaultProfile</id>
      <properties>
        ...
        <archetypeCatalog>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</archetypeCatalog>
      </properties>
 ...
```

**NOTE.** Just changed `http` to `https`.